# Illustrator eyedropper tool is picking lighter colour

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, eyedropper

I am attempting to pick the colour of the red outside of the eye in this image but the eyedropper tool keeps picking it as lighter than it actually is. The object created to the right is the colour the eyedropper has provided me and as you can see it is slightly lighter. Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It appears the image you are sampling from is a raster image- it definitely looks that way compared to the vector shape you made (showing the incorrect color sample). A raster image will have many differently shaded pixels making up what looks like a single color. Zoom into the image you are sampling from and see if this is the case and then sample the correctly colored pixel for the color you want.

Comment: I just zoomed in as far as I could and tried the eyedropper again with the same result.

Comment: There's something odd in your screenshot.  Your colour swatch is actually showing the correct picked colour, but the filled quadrilateral is showing a different colour. [see here](https://imgur.com/dmv5IH2). I would check the Appearance panel for each of these layers and objects to see if there are any blending modes or opacity changes.

Comment: Good spot! I just did as you said and each of the layers has opacity and blending mode set to default. I also tried opening a brand new file with default settings and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Illustrator's Eye Dropper Tool is set to **average** color (3x3 I think). If you want more precision, **double-click the Eyedropper Tool** in the tool bar and set it to `Point Sample`.

In addition... I see your document is in **CMYK color mode.** If you are **sampling an RGB raster image** inside a CMYK document the colors *will* be different. Not all RGB colors are possible in CMYK so Illustrator uses the closet approximation in those instances. If you want a *specific* color match, sampling with the Eye Dropper Tool is *never* the correct workflow. Use the numbers...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked my Eye Dropper tool and it was already set to point sample. I have opened an RGB colour document and tried the same thing and the colours are still off. How should I find out what the numbers are for an image if I don't have them already?

Comment: Open the raster image in a raster editor and check the *actual* color there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you embed the image into the illustrator file rather than having it linked. No idea why but it seems to work.